# Assigning reactive expression twice ignores first one

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

Shiny beginner here: I want to load a different dataset depending on which action-button gets clicked on. Since the processing from there on will be the same for any dataset, I want to store them in the same reactive expression, here `dataset()`.

See my code:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            
            actionButton("gohere", "dataset1"),
            actionButton("gothere", "dataset2")
            
        ),
        
        mainPanel(
            
            tableOutput("dataset")
            
        ),        
 
        )
    )
)



server <- function(input, output) { 
    
    
dataset <- eventReactive(input$gohere, {
    
            mtcars
        })

dataset <- eventReactive(input$gothere, {
    
            cars
    
        })
    
    
output$dataset <- renderTable({
    
    dataset()
    
        })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I expect this code to load `mtcars` into `dataset` when actionButton "gohere" is clicked and proceed with `renderTable` and to load `cars` into dataset when actionButton "gothere" is clicked and proceed likewise.

However: If I click actionButton "gothere" everything works as expected, if I click "gohere" nothing happens. If I change the order of "gohere" and "gothere" inside the `server`- function it's the other way around.

What does the second `eventReactive()` do with `dataset` that completly invalidates the first  `eventReactive()`  ?

EDIT: And if it is overwriting it, what is it overwriting it with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works like ordinary R programming: your two reactive conductors are R objects with the same name, so the second one overwrites the first one.

You can use a reactive value and some observers:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      actionButton("gohere", "dataset1"),
      actionButton("gothere", "dataset2")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("dataset")
    ),        
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) { 
  
  dataset <- reactiveVal(mtcars)
  
  observeEvent(input$gohere, {
    dataset(mtcars)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$gothere, {
    dataset(cars)
  })
  
  output$dataset <- renderTable({
    dataset()
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I thought that that might be the reason, that's why I tried with `exists()` and `is.null()` to see what happens with `dataset()` after the second `eventReactive()` but it didn't output anything. On the second actionButton I got output TRUE and FALSE, clicking on the first button there was no output.

Comment: So a question would be: What is it overwriting it with?